# Minutes between two Times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First thing i have problems with is that, although i defined in my database:

```
 add_column :patients, :wartezeit, :time
```

And in my controller:

```
 @patient.update_columns(wartezimmer: true, wartezeit: Time.now)
```

I get such an ouput for any `patient.wartezeit`:

`2000-01-01 13:48:18 UTC`  i mean this is Datetime! Im right? What did i wrong?

Next i tried to get the minutes between the `patient.wartezeit` and `Time.now`:

```
((Time.now - f.wartezeit) / 60).to_i + " minutes"
```

Somehow i get a complete wrong number of minutes! Probably because `patient.wartezeit` is defined as Datetime.

Maybe someone also has a idea for me how i have to change my code so that it not only displays minutes! Because now i get for example: `80 minutes` but `1 hour 20 minutes` woud make more sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patient. wartezeit is a `Time` element, a datetime element would look like `Sun, 17 Nov 2013 08:11:08 -0700` - As for getting how it's displayed, I usually use a gem for that.  Time and date parsing and subtraction is very easy to bungle, so for consistency I use the same thing.

https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff

This will let you do

```
diff = Time.diff( f.wartezeit, Time.now, '%y, %M, %w, %d and %H %N %S') 
diff[:diff]
```

Would render something like

```
12 hours 20 minutes 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying too hard; ActiveSupport in Rails makes this stuff easier.

```
(Time.now.minutes - f.wartezeit.minutes).to_s + ' minutes'
```

And, yes, `Time` is not a "time of day", it's a "moment in all of time" object.

Comment: I get `undefined method 'minutes'` when I run `Time.now.minutes` in my Rails 4 app.

Comment: [we need to re-level all the StackOverflow Rails verbiage for Rails4, but] what's in your activesupport numeric/time.rb file? and do other activesupport gimmicks work?